# Nonlinear model (with country and time fixed effects)

Tags: stata, nonlinear-functions, non-linear-regression

[image]

I try to estimate the above nonlinear model by Stata. Unfortunately, I am not comfortable with Stata. Can anyone help me about writing the above function in Stata?
How can we write regional dummy, time fixed effect and country fixed effect in `nl` command in Stata?
Is there a way to write the summation in the above equation in Stata? Alternatively, is it easier to estimate the equation for each individual region?

Comment: This isn't a well-posed programming problem because you do not spell out your data structure, including variable names, give a data example, or make any attempt at code. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service in which people work from a problem sketch and write code from scratch for you. You may be better off on Statalist, but even there asking several questions at once on an entire project doesn't usually evoke an answer on any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Stata 15 introduced a native command for fitting non-linear panel data models.

https://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/nonlinear-panel-data-models-with-random-effects/

That might help get you started, but you need Stata 15.